# Limit of Freemium projects reached, but only 1 active project

Tags: here-api

I created an Here Freemium account a long time ago.
I'm using geocoding and map services.

I created some projects in the past and removed them a few months ago.

Today, I want to create new projects but I can't because :
"You've reached the limit of Freemium projects for this account.
Please visit your project page to see your existing projects.
Contact us if you need another project."

But We only have 1 active project on our account..
[Here account page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgVJv.png)

Cannot we be able to create 5 freemium project ?
We tried to contact the support but the support told us to find the answer here... Anyone can give us a clue ? :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please note that you can have one Freemium plan per account

Source: email from HERE Developer.

It seems that the HERE Developer website does not cover this question, however the limit of one Freemium plan is implied in the answer of "[How do I reactivate a cancelled plan?](https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-subscription)":

> You may reactivate a cancelled Freemium **as long as there is no other active Freemium or Pro plan on this account**.

Comment: Actually, it was because the Freemium plan just changed from 5 to 1 project. The support was not very helpful on this question. Thank you btw for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In this case please contact selfservesupport@here.com
They can have a look at the details of your contract.